# Given a list and a number k return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, comparative-review, k-sum

**The task:**

> Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers
>   from the list add up to k.
>
> For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 +
>   7 is 17.
>
> Bonus: Can you do this in one pass?

```
const lst = [14, 10, 3, 7, 0];
const k = 14;
```

**My solution 1:**

```
const addUpTo = (lst, k) => lst.some((x, i) => !isNaN(lst.find((y, j) => i !== j && y === k - x)));

console.log(addUpTo(lst, k));
```

**My solution 2:**

```
const addUpTo2 = (lst, k) => lst.some((x, i) => {
  const find = k - x;
  return !isNaN(lst.slice(i + 1).find(y => y === find));
});

console.log(addUpTo2(lst, k));
```

Comment: This question is self-contained. How does this question "lack context"? What is incomplete about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These solutions have quadratic runtime.  You can store counts (in an object) and check the object for `k-x`, or sort the array, check values up to `k/2` and binary search for `k-x`.  The second approach is asymptotically slower but constant storage.